# How do I declare new app in Django rest framework? It seems everything is OK but i have RuntimeError

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to declare new app in python using Django rest framework.

First I did below steps:

```
cmd>django-admin startproject djrest .
cmd>cd djrest
cmd>django-admin startapp sarox
cmd>cd..

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'sarox',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '*******',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '****',
    }
}

cmd>python manage.py migrate
cmd>python manage.py createsuperuser
cmd>py manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:2281
```

then I declared a model in `Sarox_models.py` under `sarox` directory:

```
from django.db import models
class SaroxUsers(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(db_column='User_id', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    salt = models.CharField(db_column='Salt', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    hash = models.CharField(db_column='Hash', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    username = models.CharField(db_column='Username', unique=True, max_length=15)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'sarox_users'
```

Then I added below line to `views.py` under `sarox` directory:

```
from djrest.sarox.Sarox_models import SaroxUsers
```

and then create a line in `INSTALLED_APPS` configuration class in the `settings.py` file.

Here is my `INSTALLED_APPS` configuration class:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'sarox.apps.SaroxConfig',
    ...
]
```

My new app declared like this in `sarox/apps.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class SaroxConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'sarox'
```

But when I run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:2281` command it raises an run time error:

```
E:\MyApps\Plot\djrest>python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:2281
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AMoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\AMoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AMoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AMoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\AMoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\AMoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\AMoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AMoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\AMoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\AMoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Users\AMoha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sarox'
...
```

And when I removed the new line contains `'sarox.apps.SaroxConfig',` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` class configuration of `settings.py` everything became OK.

my project directory structure is here:

[image: direcory]

Do you have any idea?

Comment: This is a Django issue, not a "Django rest framework" one (DRF is just an add-on for "easily" creating rest APIs in Django).

Comment: And we can't help with so few informations...

Comment: Yes. this is Django issue. what kind of information do you need to help?

Comment: Well, the first obvious things would be your app's directory structure and your `sys.path`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I added picture of directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`djrest` is not your root directory, it's the 'project' directory (the directory where Django looks for settings, root urls etc), so the current python path to your "sarox" package is not `sarox` but `djrest.sarox`.

This being said, your apps shouldn't live in this directory, they should be directly in the root directory at the same level as `djrest` and `manage.py`, so the correct solution here is to leave your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` alone and move the whole sarox directory one level up.

Also, Django expects your models module to be named "models.py", not "Sarox_models.py", so you will have to fix this too (rename the module and fix all your imports) for your app to work.

As others already mentionned, using Django's `startapp` management command would have created the correct application directory structure at the right place, saving you all those troubles.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you use Django's `startapp` command? I do think you should check whether there is a `__init__.py` file under `sarox` folder though.

Comment: Yes I used `startapp` command. `__init__.py` file under  `sarox` folder is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new app in django using the command python manage.py startapp your app name. After than you can define your views and serializers with drf.